# ERROR: Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jmr17e`.`employee`,

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created a database on MySQL workbench and have made sure all of my data types are matching. I am returning this error:

```
ERROR: Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jmr17e`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `fk_employee_department` FOREIGN KEY (`dpt_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`dpt_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
SQL Code:
     INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (1, 1, 'Lila', 'Williams', 'p', '333 W Madison St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8601112233, 'lwilliams@aol.com', NULL)
```

Emp_ID and pro_ID are composite PK's to employee table and project table. They are both PK/NN/UN for the data values and the types are the same, and I have tried to look at other posts about the same error, but I cannot figure out how to fix mine from their situations. I am working in workbench, so I'm not using the script to adjust the errors - I'm trying to figure out how to adjust from the ERD so that the script when forward engineering is correct. I have attached a picture of my ERD as well. [image]

Here is the sql code:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema jmr17e
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `jmr17e` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema jmr17e
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `jmr17e` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
SHOW WARNINGS;
USE `jmr17e` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `jmr17e`.`employee`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jmr17e`.`employee` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jmr17e`.`employee` (
  `emp_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dpt_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `emp_first` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `emp_last` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `emp_type` ENUM('f', 'p') NOT NULL,
  `emp_street` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `emp_city` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `emp_state` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `emp_zip` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `emp_phone` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `emp_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_notes` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`),
  INDEX `fk_employee_department_idx` (`dpt_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employee_department`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dpt_id`)
    REFERENCES `jmr17e`.`department` (`dpt_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `jmr17e`.`division`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jmr17e`.`division` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jmr17e`.`division` (
  `div_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `div_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `div_street` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `div_city` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `div_state` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `div_zip` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `div_phone` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `div_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `div_url` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `div_notes` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`div_id`),
  INDEX `fk_division_employee1_idx` (`emp_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_division_employee1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`)
    REFERENCES `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `jmr17e`.`department`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jmr17e`.`department` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jmr17e`.`department` (
  `dpt_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `div_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dpt_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `dpt_street` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `dpt_city` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `dpt_state` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `dpt_zip` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dpt_phone` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dpt_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dpt_notes` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dpt_id`),
  INDEX `fk_department_employee1_idx` (`emp_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_department_division1_idx` (`div_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_department_employee1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`)
    REFERENCES `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_department_division1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`div_id`)
    REFERENCES `jmr17e`.`division` (`div_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `jmr17e`.`full_time`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jmr17e`.`full_time` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jmr17e`.`full_time` (
  `emp_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `annualsalary` DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_full_time_employee1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`)
    REFERENCES `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `jmr17e`.`part_time`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jmr17e`.`part_time` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jmr17e`.`part_time` (
  `emp_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hourlyrate` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `maxhourperweek` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_part_time_employee1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`)
    REFERENCES `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `jmr17e`.`project`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jmr17e`.`project` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jmr17e`.`project` (
  `pro_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pro_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `pro_notes` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pro_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `jmr17e`.`assignment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jmr17e`.`assignment` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jmr17e`.`assignment` (
  `emp_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `pro_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `asn_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `asn_start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `asn_end_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `asn_duration` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `asn_evaluation` ENUM('p', 'f') NOT NULL,
  `asn_notes` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`, `pro_id`),
  INDEX `fk_assignment_project1_idx` (`pro_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_assignment_employee1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`)
    REFERENCES `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_assignment_project1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pro_id`)
    REFERENCES `jmr17e`.`project` (`pro_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `jmr17e`.`employee`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `jmr17e`;
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (1, 1, 'Lila', 'Williams', 'p', '333 W Madison St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8601112233, 'lwilliams@aol.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (2, 2, 'Kenny', 'Smith', 'p', '444 W Madison St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8608889999, 'k.smith@gmail.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (3, 3, 'Julia', 'Riccio', 'p', '6565 W Tennessee St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8601234567, 'juliariccio@yahoo.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (4, 4, 'April', 'Jones', 'p', '7878 W Tennessee St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8601231233, 'april.jones@aol.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (5, 5, 'Hannah', 'Linkenauger', 'p', '444 N Monroe St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32303, 8607889900, 'h.linkenauger@aol.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (6, 6, 'Cody', 'Johnson', 'f', '777 N Monroe St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32303, 8604456678, 'codyj@gmail.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (7, 7, 'Josie', 'Brown', 'f', '888 White Dr', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8602214545, 'jbrown@gmail.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (8, 8, 'Bella', 'Miller', 'f', '999 White Dr', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8607879001, 'bella.m@aol.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (9, 9, 'Anthony', 'White', 'f', '901 Lipona Rd', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8605678989, 'awhite74@gmail.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (10, 10, 'Chris', 'Harris', 'f', '902 Lipona Rd', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8609001212, 'charris@yahoo.com', NULL);

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `jmr17e`.`division`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `jmr17e`;
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`division` (`div_id`, `emp_id`, `div_name`, `div_street`, `div_city`, `div_state`, `div_zip`, `div_phone`, `div_email`, `div_url`, `div_notes`) VALUES (1, 1, 'Strategy', '4343 Brevard St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8706889900, 'strategy@yahoo.com', 'strategyabc.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`division` (`div_id`, `emp_id`, `div_name`, `div_street`, `div_city`, `div_state`, `div_zip`, `div_phone`, `div_email`, `div_url`, `div_notes`) VALUES (2, 2, 'Research', '5454 Brevard St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8704453344, 'research@aol.com', 'researchabc.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`division` (`div_id`, `emp_id`, `div_name`, `div_street`, `div_city`, `div_state`, `div_zip`, `div_phone`, `div_email`, `div_url`, `div_notes`) VALUES (3, 3, 'Development', '9000 W Tennessee St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8702345678, 'development@aol.com', 'developmentabc.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`division` (`div_id`, `emp_id`, `div_name`, `div_street`, `div_city`, `div_state`, `div_zip`, `div_phone`, `div_email`, `div_url`, `div_notes`) VALUES (4, 4, 'Staffing', '1000 W Tennessee St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8706785666, 'staffing@yahoo.com', 'staffingabc.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`division` (`div_id`, `emp_id`, `div_name`, `div_street`, `div_city`, `div_state`, `div_zip`, `div_phone`, `div_email`, `div_url`, `div_notes`) VALUES (5, 5, 'Growth', '333 Oglethorpe Dr', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32303, 8703346678, 'growth@aol.com', 'growthabc.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`division` (`div_id`, `emp_id`, `div_name`, `div_street`, `div_city`, `div_state`, `div_zip`, `div_phone`, `div_email`, `div_url`, `div_notes`) VALUES (6, 6, 'Leadership', '455 Oglethorpe Dr', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32303, 8706567899, 'leadership@aol.com', 'leadershipabc.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`division` (`div_id`, `emp_id`, `div_name`, `div_street`, `div_city`, `div_state`, `div_zip`, `div_phone`, `div_email`, `div_url`, `div_notes`) VALUES (7, 7, 'Legal', '2323 N Monroe St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8703245668, 'legal@gmail.com', 'legalabc.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`division` (`div_id`, `emp_id`, `div_name`, `div_street`, `div_city`, `div_state`, `div_zip`, `div_phone`, `div_email`, `div_url`, `div_notes`) VALUES (8, 8, 'Human Resources', '4545 N Monroe St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8702238900, 'hr@aol.com', 'humanresourcesabc.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`division` (`div_id`, `emp_id`, `div_name`, `div_street`, `div_city`, `div_state`, `div_zip`, `div_phone`, `div_email`, `div_url`, `div_notes`) VALUES (9, 9, 'Quality Control', '744 Bellevue Ct', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8704568999, 'qc@yahoo.com', 'qualitycontrolabc.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`division` (`div_id`, `emp_id`, `div_name`, `div_street`, `div_city`, `div_state`, `div_zip`, `div_phone`, `div_email`, `div_url`, `div_notes`) VALUES (10, 10, 'Property', '888 Bellevue Ct', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8704590093, 'property@yahoo.com', 'propertyabc.com', NULL);

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `jmr17e`.`department`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `jmr17e`;
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`department` (`dpt_id`, `emp_id`, `div_id`, `dpt_name`, `dpt_street`, `dpt_city`, `dpt_state`, `dpt_zip`, `dpt_phone`, `dpt_email`, `dpt_notes`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'sales', '1800 Thomasville Rd', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8506783455, 'sales.abc@gmail.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`department` (`dpt_id`, `emp_id`, `div_id`, `dpt_name`, `dpt_street`, `dpt_city`, `dpt_state`, `dpt_zip`, `dpt_phone`, `dpt_email`, `dpt_notes`) VALUES (2, 2, 2, 'services', '789 N Monroe St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8507894430, 'services.tlh@yahoo.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`department` (`dpt_id`, `emp_id`, `div_id`, `dpt_name`, `dpt_street`, `dpt_city`, `dpt_state`, `dpt_zip`, `dpt_phone`, `dpt_email`, `dpt_notes`) VALUES (3, 3, 3, 'finances', '631 W Madison St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8505771101, 'pm@gmail.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`department` (`dpt_id`, `emp_id`, `div_id`, `dpt_name`, `dpt_street`, `dpt_city`, `dpt_state`, `dpt_zip`, `dpt_phone`, `dpt_email`, `dpt_notes`) VALUES (4, 4, 4, 'insurance', '700 Oglethorpe St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8506650098, 'insurance@aol.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`department` (`dpt_id`, `emp_id`, `div_id`, `dpt_name`, `dpt_street`, `dpt_city`, `dpt_state`, `dpt_zip`, `dpt_phone`, `dpt_email`, `dpt_notes`) VALUES (5, 5, 5, 'marketing', '213 N Lipona Dr', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8503324545, 'marketing@gmail.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`department` (`dpt_id`, `emp_id`, `div_id`, `dpt_name`, `dpt_street`, `dpt_city`, `dpt_state`, `dpt_zip`, `dpt_phone`, `dpt_email`, `dpt_notes`) VALUES (6, 6, 6, 'web design', '614 W Madison St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 2038924527, 'itservices@yahoo.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`department` (`dpt_id`, `emp_id`, `div_id`, `dpt_name`, `dpt_street`, `dpt_city`, `dpt_state`, `dpt_zip`, `dpt_phone`, `dpt_email`, `dpt_notes`) VALUES (7, 7, 7, 'public relations', '200 College Ave', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8509008765, 'pr@yahoo.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`department` (`dpt_id`, `emp_id`, `div_id`, `dpt_name`, `dpt_street`, `dpt_city`, `dpt_state`, `dpt_zip`, `dpt_phone`, `dpt_email`, `dpt_notes`) VALUES (8, 8, 8, 'production', '1777 W Tennessee St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32301, 8509874433, 'production@gmail.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`department` (`dpt_id`, `emp_id`, `div_id`, `dpt_name`, `dpt_street`, `dpt_city`, `dpt_state`, `dpt_zip`, `dpt_phone`, `dpt_email`, `dpt_notes`) VALUES (9, 9, 9, 'purchasing', '456 N Monroe St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32303, 8507782221, 'purchasing@yahoo.com', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`department` (`dpt_id`, `emp_id`, `div_id`, `dpt_name`, `dpt_street`, `dpt_city`, `dpt_state`, `dpt_zip`, `dpt_phone`, `dpt_email`, `dpt_notes`) VALUES (10, 10, 10, 'operations', '4545 Northern Blvd', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32303, 8505668899, 'operations@aol.com', NULL);

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `jmr17e`.`full_time`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `jmr17e`;
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`full_time` (`emp_id`, `annualsalary`) VALUES (1, 89000.45);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`full_time` (`emp_id`, `annualsalary`) VALUES (2, 91000.50);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`full_time` (`emp_id`, `annualsalary`) VALUES (3, 92000.05);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`full_time` (`emp_id`, `annualsalary`) VALUES (4, 94000.01);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`full_time` (`emp_id`, `annualsalary`) VALUES (5, 95000.75);

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `jmr17e`.`part_time`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `jmr17e`;
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`part_time` (`emp_id`, `hourlyrate`, `maxhourperweek`) VALUES (6, 15.50, 60);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`part_time` (`emp_id`, `hourlyrate`, `maxhourperweek`) VALUES (7, 23.50, 60);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`part_time` (`emp_id`, `hourlyrate`, `maxhourperweek`) VALUES (8, 22.50, 60);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`part_time` (`emp_id`, `hourlyrate`, `maxhourperweek`) VALUES (9, 34.50, 40);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`part_time` (`emp_id`, `hourlyrate`, `maxhourperweek`) VALUES (10, 32.75, 40);

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `jmr17e`.`project`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `jmr17e`;
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`project` (`pro_id`, `pro_name`, `pro_notes`) VALUES (1, 'presentation', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`project` (`pro_id`, `pro_name`, `pro_notes`) VALUES (2, 'report', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`project` (`pro_id`, `pro_name`, `pro_notes`) VALUES (3, 'brief', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`project` (`pro_id`, `pro_name`, `pro_notes`) VALUES (4, 'pamphlet', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`project` (`pro_id`, `pro_name`, `pro_notes`) VALUES (5, 'speech', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`project` (`pro_id`, `pro_name`, `pro_notes`) VALUES (6, 'poster', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`project` (`pro_id`, `pro_name`, `pro_notes`) VALUES (7, 'signage', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`project` (`pro_id`, `pro_name`, `pro_notes`) VALUES (8, 'mockup', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`project` (`pro_id`, `pro_name`, `pro_notes`) VALUES (9, 'draft', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`project` (`pro_id`, `pro_name`, `pro_notes`) VALUES (10, 'model', NULL);

COMMIT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `jmr17e`.`assignment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `jmr17e`;
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`assignment` (`emp_id`, `pro_id`, `asn_name`, `asn_start_date`, `asn_end_date`, `asn_duration`, `asn_evaluation`, `asn_notes`) VALUES (1, 1, 'january', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-30', 'one month', 'p', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`assignment` (`emp_id`, `pro_id`, `asn_name`, `asn_start_date`, `asn_end_date`, `asn_duration`, `asn_evaluation`, `asn_notes`) VALUES (2, 2, 'february', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-28', 'one month', 'p', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`assignment` (`emp_id`, `pro_id`, `asn_name`, `asn_start_date`, `asn_end_date`, `asn_duration`, `asn_evaluation`, `asn_notes`) VALUES (3, 3, 'march', '2019-03-01', '2019-03-31', 'one month', 'p', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`assignment` (`emp_id`, `pro_id`, `asn_name`, `asn_start_date`, `asn_end_date`, `asn_duration`, `asn_evaluation`, `asn_notes`) VALUES (4, 4, 'april', '2019-04-01', '2019-04-30', 'one month', 'p', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`assignment` (`emp_id`, `pro_id`, `asn_name`, `asn_start_date`, `asn_end_date`, `asn_duration`, `asn_evaluation`, `asn_notes`) VALUES (5, 5, 'may', '2019-05-01', '2019-05-30', 'one month', 'p', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`assignment` (`emp_id`, `pro_id`, `asn_name`, `asn_start_date`, `asn_end_date`, `asn_duration`, `asn_evaluation`, `asn_notes`) VALUES (6, 6, 'june', '2019-06-01', '2019-06-30', 'one month', 'f', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`assignment` (`emp_id`, `pro_id`, `asn_name`, `asn_start_date`, `asn_end_date`, `asn_duration`, `asn_evaluation`, `asn_notes`) VALUES (7, 7, 'july', '2019-07-01', '2019-07-31', 'one month', 'f', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`assignment` (`emp_id`, `pro_id`, `asn_name`, `asn_start_date`, `asn_end_date`, `asn_duration`, `asn_evaluation`, `asn_notes`) VALUES (8, 8, 'august', '2019-08-01', '2019-08-30', 'one month', 'f', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`assignment` (`emp_id`, `pro_id`, `asn_name`, `asn_start_date`, `asn_end_date`, `asn_duration`, `asn_evaluation`, `asn_notes`) VALUES (9, 9, 'september', '2019-09-01', '2019-09-30', 'one month', 'f', NULL);
INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`assignment` (`emp_id`, `pro_id`, `asn_name`, `asn_start_date`, `asn_end_date`, `asn_duration`, `asn_evaluation`, `asn_notes`) VALUES (10, 10, 'october', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-31', 'one month', 'f', NULL);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: `pro_id` is `UNSIGNED` in `assignment`, but not in `project`. They have to be the same type.

Comment: Use this `'pro_id' INT(11) NOT NULL,_` in assignment table for pro_id column.

Comment: ERROR: Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jmr17e`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `fk_employee_department` FOREIGN KEY (`dpt_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`dpt_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
SQL Code:
        INSERT INTO `jmr17e`.`employee` (`emp_id`, `dpt_id`, `emp_first`, `emp_last`, `emp_type`, `emp_street`, `emp_city`, `emp_state`, `emp_zip`, `emp_phone`, `emp_email`, `emp_notes`) VALUES (1, 1, 'Lila', 'Williams', 'p', '333 W Madison St', 'Tallahassee', 'FL', 32304, 8601112233, 'lwilliams@aol.com', NULL)

Comment: is the new error I am getting^